# Как получить response, используя $.postJson()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, selenium

Задача состоит в получении ответа, используя ***IJavaScriptExecutor*** и метод ***$.postJson()***
Реализация следующая. Имеется класс:

```
class ExecuteJavaScript
{
    public IWebDriver driver;

    public ExecuteJavaScript(IWebDriver driver) => this.driver = driver;

    public object Execute(string endPoint, string data)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        return (js.ExecuteAsyncScript("$.postJSON('" + endPoint + "', " + data + ")"));
    }
}
```

И его вызов:

```
        string url = "http://...";
        var data = SomeClass.GetBodyObject;
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        var response = new ExecuteJavaScript(driver).Execute(url, body);
```

Запрос выполняется отлично, делает все что нужно. Однако ответа никакого не приходит. Хотя в ответе тоже должен быть Json.
Если сделать этот же реквест с использованием ***HttpClient*** или ***HttpWebRequest*** то ответ от сервера приходит корректный. 
Но мне необходимо отправлять запрос непосредственно через браузер средствами Селениума.

Может у кого найдется решение проблемы, заранее спасибо.

Comment: а на приеме у вас есть контроллер?

Comment: доступа к исходному коду сервера у меня в данный момент нет и его логика работы мне также не известна.